# Streaming synchronized media to multiple devices over WiFi

Tags: synchronization, streaming, media, vlc, rtp

I want to stream synchronized media to multiple devices (also called multi-room audio), similar to what is done with Sonos or AirPlay. I figured this would be easy to do using RTP multicast, as you only need to set up one multicast stream using VLC (or  a GStreamer/ffmpeg/etc. server) to which all clients can connect. This seems to work fine over ethernet, but causes problems over WiFi (apparently due to low bandwidth allocation for multicast packets on most routers).

A syncronized VLC streaming setup described [here](http://www.hackedexistence.com/project-vlc.html) is a good solution, but only works with an earlier version of VLC (0.8.6b).

Are there any other options for synchronized media streaming over WiFi?

Answer (score 2):

A few months later, and I finally have an answer to my own question.

The best solution seems to be to use Logitech Media Server (aka SqueezeCenter) as a streaming server and Logitech [Squeezeboxes](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/speakers-audio/wireless-music-systems/devices/squeezebox-radio-black) (HW solution) and/or SqueezePlay (SW solution for Mac/Win/Linux) for media playback. SqueezePlay and Media Server are free and a Squeezebox is around €140/$180. You can also use the Squeezebox apps on Android/iOS as controllers.

I have tested [synchronization](http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/Synchronization) between two Squeezeboxes and one SqueezePlay instance (Mac) connected to a Media Server (Linux) and it worked without problems. The streaming protocol and how synchronization is performed is explained [here](http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/Design_of_new-streaming).

If you want to programmatically control the devices, there is a Logitech SqueezeCenter Telnet CLI (see Help > Technical Information > Command Line Interface on the Logitech Media Server), as well as a [Python wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/pysqueezecenter/) for the CLI.